# Which Windows API in C++ will help me in identifying which Dialog Class the Current ComboBox is using?

Tags: winapi, mfc

How can I know that for a particular ComboBox which Dialog Style is being used? Is there any Win32 API which can give me that information?

I am using `CDialog` for a few ComboBox, `CDialogEx` for some, and an in-house Dialog class, let's say `Ctl3dDialogEx`, for others. `GetClassName()` will return the Class name of the ComboBox (if I am passing a ComboBox Handler) which can be `"CComboBox"`.

Is there any Win32 API where I will pass the ComboBox Handler and it will return back to me the Dialog class name, for eg : `"CDialog"`, `"CDialogEx"`, `"Ctl3dDialogEx"`, etc?

Below code will help to understand maybe:

```
void ComboBox_DoSomeManipulation( HWND hldg , int n )
{
    /*"hldg" is the handler of the Current ComBobox */

    LPTSTR lpClassName;

    int nMaxCount = 256; 

     /*This will return "CComboBox" as value in lpClassName */

    GetClassName(hldg , lpClassName ,  _count_of(nMaxCount));             

    /*Is there any WIN API like above which can give */
    /* Dialog class information like CDialog, CDialogEx */
    /* which the ComboBox is using ? */            
}
```

Comment: *All* dialogs share the same class name, `#32770`, as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#system-classes).

Comment: I had a reasonable answer and then it was closed--prematurely. I understand the question, I think.

Comment: He wants to be able to get the CRuntimeClass* basically, Win API won't help here because all the dialogs are the DIALOG class (#32770) as @IInspectable noted.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson  Please help if you have any kind of suggestion, I have redefined the question once again.

Comment: Any Suggestion I will highly appreciate that , even if you can direct me to some sample code maybe where it was achieved even that will help as well.

Comment: @Joseph Willcoxson - Yeah, I also think it's clear what is being asked! My answer would be suggesting use of dynamic_cast<> on a pointer to the parent.

Comment: I can't help you. Since they closed the question... Basically, use CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hdlg) to get a CWnd*.  From that pointer, call GetRuntimeClass() to get the runtime class and compare with RUNTIME_CLASS(CDialog), or RUNTIME_CLASS(CDialogEx), etc.

Comment: Joseph Willcoxson thanks a lot for your help . Now I am trying to figure out how the question can be opened :) .. not sure why it's closed, I have redefined the question and I hope this time it's making sense now :) , Thanks Once again I will investigate more on this line . @Adrian Thanks for your understanding as well. At least two members were able to get my point  :)

Comment: I voted to reopen. Others can vote to reopen as well. I'm not sure if you need a certain level of points to reopen.

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson -- really appreciate that

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson - You need 3,000 reputation to be able to vote to reopen. It'll be at least a week before I get to that level!

Comment: Note that `GetClassName(hldg , lpClassName ,  _count_of(nMaxCount));` will fail as shown. There is no memory being allocated for `lpClassName`, and `_count_of()` requires a fixed array as input, not an integer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Thanks, my bad, I was quickly writing some code just to make sure the members get some Idea about what I am trying to achieve. I need to take an array indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If your combo-box can somehow get hold of a **genuine** pointer to its parent window, then you can use `dynamic_cast<CDialogEx*>(pParent)` to see if it's `CDialogEx` (returns `nullptr` if not). You will need several separate checks, starting from the most derived class! So, if your `Ctl3dDialogEx` is derived from `CDialogEx`, then:

```
. . .
CWnd *pParent = pCombo->GetParent(); // This, as is, is not valid code!
if (dynamic_cast<Ctl3dDialogEx*>(pParent) != nullptr) {
    // It's a Ctl3dDialogEx parent
}
else if (dynamic_cast<CDialogEx*>(pParent) != nullptr) {
    // It's a CDialogEx
}
else { // Assuming no other options …
    // It's a CDialog
}
```

I would recommend making an accessible (static?) copy of the parent window's `this` pointer during initialisation, if you can. But there are other ways …

For example, assuming you have control over the definition of `ComboBox_DoSomeManipulation` and when it's called, change the first argument from an `HWND` to a `CWnd*` and, when you call it, use `this` rather than `this->m_hwnd`. (But this depends on the structure of your code!)

Comment: @Joseph Willcoxson This is 'similar' to comparison with `RUNTIME_CLASS(CDialogEx)` calls but, IMHO, simpler and more standard.

Comment: I edited my answer now, because I misunderstood how `CWnd::FromHandlePermanent` works! If this really runs through a list of system `HWND` objects and sees what (if any) container class object they are attached to, then that will probably work, too!

Comment: CWnd::FromHandle() will always return a CWnd*. If it isn't in the permanent map, then it will create a CWnd* in the temporary map. If you don't have just one application, or are using all extension DLLs, you can get get unexpected results if you have a mix of extension and usr dlls, like in the case of an MFC COM server. You want to be sure you are using the same MFC instance (handle maps, GetMessage() loop, etc). Calling CWnd::FromHandlePermanent() ensures that you are using same MFC instance. It will return NULL if not the same MFC instance.

Comment: Thanks for all your input really appreciate it . I tried using CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hdlg); But this is returning NULL . So I cannot do any GetRuntimeClass() on that pointer. As a alternative I was trying to use CWnd::FromHandle(hDlg) , It does return back a pointer , so when I did pWnd->GetRuntimeClass() it is showing me "CComboBox" as class name . So I am just wondering what else I can try . Please note that the function ComboBox_DoSomeManipulation is in a non-MFC code base . Once again really appreciate all the inputs so far

Comment: From what you say, it seems that the `hldg` parameter in your function is the `HWND` of the combo-box control itself, not that of the parent dialog box. But I'm still a bit confused why `::FromHandlePermanent` returns `NULL` but `::FromHandle` gives a `RunTimeClass` of `CComboBox`. Maybe MFC is doing something 'clever' with the `HWND` object?

Comment: may be, I am still trying to figure that out. In the meantime, I tried pComb->GetParent()->GetRuntimeClass() and I can see at least for the MFC classes I am able to compare the Dialog class ( I am not calling any  ::FromHandlePermanent  or  ::FromHandle) . The problem is that there is a combinatiion  of MFC and non-MFC code trying to call the same API and that's where things are going wrong

Comment: Yeah, something weird is happening. hDlg appears to be for the combo. I guess I'd try:  CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(::GetParrent(hDlg)) to try and get a CWnd* to the dialog.  Calling pCombo->GetParent() basically calls ::GetParent(pComobo->m_hWnd) followed by CWnd::FromHandle() on the HWND returned from ::GetParent() windows API function.  If you are using MFC correctly (and have the same MFC instance), then you should nearly always get a vaild CWnd* back from CWnd::FromHandlePermanent() with the window handle from a dialog. pCombo->GetParent() should be returning a CDialog derived pointer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Windows API help since all those dialogs will be subclassing the Windows DIALOG class. If this is all in process, and you are using the same MFC instance, you might be able to do this:

```
CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hdlg);

if (pWnd != NULL)
{
   if (pWnd->GetRuntimeClass() == RUNTIME_CLASS(CDialog))
   {
   }
   else if (pWnd->GetRuntimeClass() == RUNTIME_CLASS(CDialogEx))
   {
   }
   else if (pWnd->GetRuntimeClass() == RUNTIME_CLASS(CDialogxyz))
   {
   }
}
```

Back in the old days, MS compilers used with MFC didn't play well with dynamic_cast<>, so generally, when using MFC, I don't use it. I probably should have more trust in it, but I was stuck using Visual C++ 6 until 2008, so I am probably a little jaded.  The more "standard" "MFC way" is to use the MFC macros...

Another possible ways is something like:

```
if (CDialogxyz* pDlgxyz = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CDialogxyz, pWnd))
{
}
else if (CDialogEx* pDlgEx = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CDialogEx, pWnd))
{
}
else if (CDialog* pDlg = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CDialog, pWnd))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your input really appreciate it . I tried using 

CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(hdlg);
But this is returning NULL . So I cannot do any GetRuntimeClass() on that pointer.  As a alternative I was trying to use CWnd::FromHandle(hDlg) , It does return back a pointer , so when I did pWnd->GetRuntimeClass() it is showing me "CComboBox" as class name . So I am just wondering what else I can try . Please note that the function ComboBox_DoSomeManipulation is in a non-MFC code base . Once again really appreciate all the inputs so far.